# Prove that $f(x)=x\sin(x)$ is not a uniformly continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I have this problem, and im really lost here, i need to show that.
$f(x)=x\sin x$ is not an uniformly continuous function.

Comment: no, at least in my notes says xsin(x)

Comment: Then edit your question to say the same, @Zigisfredo. You wrote  $sen(x)$ not $\sin(x)$.

Comment: yes, i just notice that, sorry, im not an native english speaker so its a little confusing...

Comment: look near points at which $\sin(x)=0$ the function has bigger and bigger slope at such points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sequences $x_n = 2n \pi$ and $y_n = 2n \pi + 1/n$.

What happens to $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n-y_n)$?

What happens to $f(x_n) - f(y_n)$?

Comment: so, with those sequences, i can say that the limn→∞(xn−yn) converges to 0, and therefore i can say its a cauchy sequence, then if f is uniformly continuous it should preserve cauchy property?

Comment: One way to classify non-uniform continuity is to pick two sequences that get arbitrarily close to each other but the function values along these two sequences are always bounded away from $0$, i.e., $\vert f(x_n) - f(y_n) \vert > \epsilon_0$ for some $\epsilon_0$.

Comment: Oh, ok! i think i can make this exercice now, i really appreciate it, thanks!